# Remove an item in AsyncStorage using FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

Sorry for the inexperience, but how do I remove an Item in Async Storage renderized in Flat List, for example:

This is my component that creates a flatlist

```
export default function Saved() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function getStorage() {
      const nomeStorage = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      if (nomeStorage != null) {
        setColors(nomeStorage);
      }
    }

    getStorage();

  }, [colors])

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>

      <FlatList
        data={colors}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Saveds data={item} />}
      />

    </View>
  );
}
```

and this is my FlatList renderized component

```
export default function Saveds(props) {
  return (
    <View>

      <View style={styles.Boxes}>
        <Box color={props.data}>
          <Badge
            badgeStyle={styles.badge}
            value={<Text style={styles.color}>{props.data}</Text>}
          />
        </Box>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
          <Icon name={'trash-outline'} color={'#FFF'} size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}
```

I need one way to when I click in my TouchableOpacity, I delete the selected data in my AsyncStorage.

The name in my AsyncStorage is the same as the value, so I can delete the AsyncStorage getting the value of my props.data.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting from your async storage should be as easy as just calling `AsyncStorage.removeItem(key)`

I had some similar functionality in an app that I made a while ago, I attached the delete function call to the onLongPress prop of touchableOpacity:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UserScreen', data)}
  onLongPress={handleLongPress}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    // ...
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And earlier in the component, I defined a function that handles the deleting:

```
const handleLongPress = async () => {
  // In your instance, you should be OK to replace data.key with props.data
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem(data.key);

  /* I then had another function that was passed in as a prop
  to update another component when the deletion had taken place */
  await onChange();
};
```